# Django threaded / nested comments

Tags: django, mptt, threaded-comments

What's the best way to implement threaded/nested comments in Django? I've read a bit about `MPTT` and `django-threadedcomments` but all the posts seem to be from years ago. Is using `MPTT` still the 'accepted' way or is there a newer way to do it?